# An Active and Passive Gerund

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds, active-voice

I'm really stuck on paraphrasing the sentences bellow using gerund.

> 1. That she is so fussy is not a little unpleasant.
> 2. What surprised everybody was that he was able to do it.

Here are some of my variants:

> 1. It's not a little unpleasant of being her so fussy.
> 2. Everybody was surprised by his managing to do it.

I'm not sure if it is correct or not.

Comment: No need to shout about it.

Comment: 'Her being so fussy is not a little unpleasant' (though in real English, 'She's so fussy it's quite annoying' ). // 'His managing to do it was what surprised everybody' (if we're allowed the verb change). Your variant is grammatical, but sounds even worse than this.  Idiomatically, 'Everybody was surprised when he managed to do it'.

Comment: But in the first variant is it correct to use preposition "of" ? 

1. It's not a little unpleasant of being her so fussy.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you're more likely to find help for this if you ask on [ell.se] instead.

Comment: 'It's not a little unpleasant of her, being so fussy.' is grammatical. But few native speakers would say it.

Comment: One might say "Being so fussy is what she is all about". "Her being so fussy is more than unpleasant". I can easily imagine saying both those sentences....

Answer (score 0):

The "that" clause in these sentences is nominal: It acts like a noun.

This nominal clause can be replace with a gerund.

"That she is so funny"  -> "her being so funny"

The noun (is) is changed to a gerund, and if the subject of the clause is a pronoun (she) it is changed to the possessive form (her). The rest of the sentence is unchanged. "Her being so funny is not a little unpleasant."

Similarly in the second example: "What surprised everybody was his being able to do it." Since the gerund has no tense, "was" -> "being", the tense is implied by the tense of the main verb.

Both of these examples are rather forced. There are better ways to express this "I know she's really funny, but at times it gets on my nerves. Do you know what I mean?" ...